# Como manipular o retorno de uma consulta no banco em PHP

Tags: php, sql, data-manipulation

Estou com dificuldades em criar a lógica para a manipulação/tratamento dos dados que recebo de uma consulta SQL no banco. Minha consulta está retornando um array no seguinte formato:

Meu array:

```
array = {0: (id =1, nome = fulano, id_categoria= 5 categoria="formulario de 
            teste") ;
1:(id =2, nome = ciclano, id_categoria= 3 categoria="formulario de registro");
2:(id =3, nome = beltrano, id_categoria= 3 categoria="formulario de teste")}
```

Eu gostaria de fazer o tratamento deste array para agrupar os `id` e `nome` da tabela 1 por categoria da tabela 2. Minha dúvida é se existe uma forma de converter esse array em um objeto, ou se existe alguma outra forma no PHP que eu consiga acessar esses dados separadamente.

Comment: Por que não altera a consulta ao banco de dados para já trazer do jeito que você quer? Como é a sua consulta atual?

Comment: altere o fetch de modo a adequar-se ao que precisas